# Excel - how do I autofill a pattern of cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Looking for a formula or shortcut to help with autofilling a "cell pattern". Rows 357 through 365 is the pattern I want copied across to 366 through 374:

![Rows 357 through 365 is the pattern I want copied across to 366 through 374.][1]

**I need to keep the text and numbers unique - I only want the pattern, not what's in the cells.**

If the link is busted, I want the pattern to look like this

```
[text A][blank][blank][blank][blank][blank][blank]

[text A][blank][blank][blank][blank][text F][text G]

[text A][text B][text C][text D][text E][text F][text G]
```

For each set of 3 rows, texts A through G are unique. **I only want the pattern, not the cell contents.**

Thanks for your help. :)

Edit:
Here's an example of the data I have:

[image: example]

Here's what I want it to look like:

[image: want]

I need to copy that format down through the rest of the worksheet. It currently looks like this:

[image: this]

but I want it to look like this:

[image: this].

Comment: If you don't want the content of the cells, it's unclear to me what you want to copy, Can yo u[edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1400781/edit) to show us what data you have and the expected result (two separate screen caps would be helpful here)

Comment: copy-> paste special -> format only, is that what you want?

Comment: Your first image reference doesn't have a link (there might be a limit as a new user).  Can you try again to add that, or put it in a comment?

Answer (score 0):

1. Work from a backup copy.
2. Add a filter. Filter for blank column B. Delete all those rows. ** Turn off the filter.
3. Add '3' in column H to every row. ***
4. Copy everything. **** Note how many rows you have. Paste below the existing data. Change the '3' in every newly-copied row to a '2'.
5. Copy all the '3' rows again. Paste below the existing data again. Change the '3' in all the new rows to '1'.
6. Sort your data numerically by row D, then row H.
7. Add a filter. Filter row H to show only '1'.
8. Delete everything in rows B-G.
9. Change the filter to show row H '2' values.
10. Delete everything in rows B-E.
11. Unfilter. Remove the filter. Delete column H entirely.
12. Profit?

** If you find it amenable to delete the rows, simply do that. You can also select all the data, delete that, then unfilter and re-sort on anything to push the blank rows to the bottom (this does have the unpleasant side effect of retaining a bunch of blank rows below your data, though).

*** Add '3' to column H in the first row containing data. Press ctrl+c to copy that '3'. Press left arrow (now you're in column G, which (presumably) has data all the way down). Press ctrl+down. Press right. Press ctrl+shift+up arrow. Press ctrl+v.

**** Ctrl+A might do the trick here (not if you deleted data rather than rows in step 2). Another good technique is, from anywhere, press ctrl+end. Then ctrl+shift+home. (Then ctrl+c to copy)

EDIT: I guess it should be noted that this solution is nothing to do with 'autofill' in any meaningful way. I don't know of any native features (you could of course use VB) that allow you to 'select every nth row and copy a subset of its values up one row'. This solution does have the advantages of being fast, dead easy, and perfectly effective.